Spring Kafka with Azure Event Hub- could not be established. Broker may not be available
I am trying to send messages using spring cloud kafka stream to Azure Event Hub.
Azure Example
The reference guide by spring (mentioned in azure documentation) is binder
Error:
[AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2024-08-30T18:21:08.224+01:00  INFO 15160 --- [springkafkaeventhub] [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.6.2
2024-08-30T18:21:08.224+01:00  INFO 15160 --- [springkafkaeventhub] [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: c4deed513057c94e
2024-08-30T18:21:08.224+01:00  INFO 15160 --- [springkafkaeventhub] [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1725038468223
2024-08-30T18:21:08.236+01:00  INFO 15160 --- [springkafkaeventhub] [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-08-30T18:21:08.237+01:00  WARN 15160 --- [springkafkaeventhub] [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Though it says warning, consumer and producer are not working - no messages are sent or received.
Explanantion:
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

application props
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.connection-string=Endpoint=sb://
spring.cloud.function.definition=consume;supply
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consume-in-0.destination=demo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consume-in-0.group=$Default
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.supply-out-0.destination=demo

Application with restcontroller
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringkafkaeventhubApplication.class, args);
}

private static final Sinks.Many<Message<String>> many = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> supply() {
    return ()->many.asFlux()
            .doOnNext(m->log.info("Manually sending message {}", m))
            .doOnError(t->log.error("Error encountered", t));
}

@GetMapping("/send")
public String sendMessage(@RequestParam String content) {
    many.emitNext(new GenericMessage<>(content), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);
    return content;
}

@Bean
public Consumer<Message<String>> consume() {
    return message->log.info("New message received: '{}'", message.getPayload());
}



    <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.12.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    spring boot version: <version>3.2.6</version>

Why the code expects a local broker? what is the fix please ?

Found the fix:
Added the property in application props.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/kafka-support?tabs=SpringCloudAzure5x
